# How to overlap .NET UI control on a map

Tags: c#, user-interface, sharpmap

I wanted to set multiple Symbols on a same Layer but, as far as I know, **SharpMap (v4.0)** does not support this. So I decided to set a lonely **Layer populated by Points** and "paste" **dotNet UserInterfaces over each point**.

Each interactive UI have its own object declared inside that will condition its attributes such as the image shown, if its visible or not, etc...

So, **how can I link those UI location to their corresponding layer points?** I've been trying method "*MapControl*.PointToScreen()" but does nothing, need something like this:

*myUI.Location = myPoint.Coordinate;*

Simple examples or just other points of view of the problem would be awesome and very welcome. Thx!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

*PointF myScreen_Fpoint = mapControl.Map.WorldToImage(MapCoord);*